# Ensuring safe JSON, XML and YAML loading in Django project

Tags: python, django, security

I'm maintaining a production Django 1.5 application.

Recently there was a lot of noise about various vulnerabilities related to the loading of JSON, XML and YAML objects. If I understand correctly, input was carefully crafted to exploit bugs in the loading functions.

Now, I have no idea where Django (or the dozens of third-party apps that we use) use each of these protocols. How can I be safe from such vulnerabilities? Do I need to make sure in some way that Django is loading JSON, XML and YAML safely?

Comment: Making sure that Django is loading JSON, XML and YAML safely is the Django developers' job. I can assure you, there are probably more security issues in your code than in Django's (though those obviously have more impact and are more likely to be found).

Comment: What noise are you referring to? Any links on specifics?

Comment: I believe he is talking about the [Rails YAML exploit](http://rubysource.com/anatomy-of-an-exploit-an-in-depth-look-at-the-rails-yaml-vulnerability/) and the [Python XML library parsing DOS attack vectors](http://blog.python.org/2013/02/announcing-defusedxml-fixes-for-xml.html).

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't accept user encoded input in these formats by default and in general third-party apps won't either, but it's worth auditing the parts that are user-facing to be sure. The big ones are going to be API providers (Tastypie, Django REST Framework, etc.). If you're on current versions you should be safe, but it's worth testing/confirming.

If you are loading anything in your app from these formats, be sure to use [`defusedxml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/defusedxml) and YAMLs [`safe_load`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#LoadingYAML) method. The standard library `json` module should be safe from these sorts of exploits.